# Custom JavaScript modal window not showing as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery

A delete button fires off a custom JavaScript modal window that requests a delete confirmation. On a Yes, I then fire off a call to a web api to do the delete. After the return from the call, I then want to show another modal window to display a "successful delete" message. Then I wan to move onto a different view.

Problem is, it's moving on to the different view before it shows my 2nd modal. Why?

I used this as an example: https://learnersbucket.com/examples/bootstrap4/custom-confirm-box-with-bootstrap/

```
<script type="text/javascript">

The 1st modal:

function ConfirmDeleteProfile(handler) {
    $(`<div class="modal fade" id="myModal1" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
               <div class="modal-body" style="padding:10px;">
               <h4 class="text-center">Are you sure you want to delete your profile ?</h4>
               <div class="text-center">
                   <a class="btn btn-info btn-yes1">Yes</a>
                   <a class="btn btn-default btn-no1">No</a>
                </div>
             </div>
         </div>
       </div>
    </div>`).appendTo('body');

    $("#myModal1").modal({
        backdrop: 'static',
        keyboard: false
    });

    $(".btn-yes1").click(function () {
        $("#myModal1").modal("hide");

        var url = '@Url.Content("~/")' + "UserProfile/DeleteUserProfile";

        $.post(url, function (data) {
            if (data) {
               var returnStatus = false;

               // Show another modal.
               returnStatus = ConfirmSuccessfulDelete();

               // Goes to another view.
               var url2 = '@Url.Content("~/")' + "Home/Index";
               window.location.href = url2;

               handler(true);
            }
            else {
                alert("Something went wrong with the delete!");
                return false;
            }
        });
    });

    $(".btn-no1").click(function () {
        handler(false);
        $("#myModal1").modal("hide");
    });

    $("#myModal1").on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
        $("#myModal1").remove();
    });
}

    The 2nd modal:

    function ConfirmSuccessfulDelete(handler) {
    $(`<div class="modal fade" id="myModal5" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
             <div class="modal-content">
               <div class="modal-body" style="padding:10px;">
               <h4 class="text-center">Your Profile Has Been Deleted Successfully.</h4>
               </br>
               <h4 class="text-center">You can always recreate it if you are so inclined.</h4>
               <div class="text-center">
                   <a class="btn btn-info btn-ok5">OK</a>
                </div>
             </div>
         </div>
       </div>
    </div>`).appendTo('body');

    // Trigger the modal.
    $("#myModal5").modal({
        backdrop: 'static',
        keyboard: false
    });

    $(".btn-ok5").click(function () {
        handler(true);
        $("#myModal5").modal("hide");
    });

    $("#myModal5").on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
        $("#myModal5").remove();
    });
}
</script>
```

---

I have a test version with alerts. The alerts appear then the 2nd modal window appears.

Again why?

```
    function ConfirmDeleteProfile(handler) {
    $(`<div class="modal fade" id="myModal1" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
               <div class="modal-body" style="padding:10px;">
               <h4 class="text-center">Are you sure you want to delete your profile ?</h4>
               <div class="text-center">
                   <a class="btn btn-info btn-yes1">Yes</a>
                   <a class="btn btn-default btn-no1">No</a>
                </div>
             </div>
         </div>
       </div>
    </div>`).appendTo('body');

    $("#myModal1").modal({
        backdrop: 'static',
        keyboard: false
    });

    $(".btn-yes1").click(function () {
        $("#myModal1").modal("hide");

        var url = '@Url.Content("~/")' + "UserProfile/DeleteUserProfile";

        $.post(url, function (data) {
            if (data) {
                var returnStatus = false;
                returnStatus = ConfirmSuccessfulDelete();

                if (returnStatus == true) {
                   alert('true')
                }
                else {
                   alert('false')
                }

                handler(true);
            }
            else {
                alert("Something went wrong with the delete!");
                return false;
            }
        });
    });

    // Pass false to callback function.
    $(".btn-no1").click(function () {
        handler(false);
        $("#myModal1").modal("hide");
    });

    // Remove the modal once it is closed.
    $("#myModal1").on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
        $("#myModal1").remove();
    });
}
```

Comment: Custom modal dialogs are not really modal, they don't block the execution of the script, and `window.location.href = ...` changes the page immediately after the dialog appears. You've to create a listener for the OK button in the second dialog too, and redirect from that handler function.

Comment: In addition to what is written above,why do you create the modal in the action.Normally I create all modals hidden on page load or document ready and then just hide/ unhide and replace the info I have too. Much quicker and smoother.

Comment: Codebreaker007...do you have an example? I used this as a guide: https://learnersbucket.com/examples/bootstrap4/custom-confirm-box-with-bootstrap/

Comment: Teemu, similar to what I used as a reference, I added (handler) to both and then included handler(true); or handler(false); depending. Is that what you mean? And it had no affect. It runs the same. I now noticed I get: Uncaught TypeError: handler is not a function

Comment: Teemu, In the ConfirmDeleteProfile(handler), I just added: ConfirmSuccessfulDelete( (ans) => {
                        if (ans) {
                            var url2 = '@Url.Content("~/")' + "Home/Index";
                            window.location.href = url2;
                        } else {
                            alert('Error')
                        }
                    }); It now works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the ConfirmDeleteProfile(handler), I just added: ConfirmSuccessfulDelete( (ans) => { if (ans) { var url2 = '@Url.Content("~/")' + "Home/Index"; window.location.href = url2; } else { alert('Error') } });